# Scanning of the variables

Tags: variables, if-statement

I use a LINUX os and GCC complier. When I run this code,

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
        int age;
        char col;
        printf("Enter a age ");
        scanf("%d",&age);
        printf("Enter a college:");
        scanf("%c",&col);
        if(age>=25 && (col=='H' || col=='Y'))
        printf("Harvard");
        else
        printf("Yale");
        return 0;
        }
```

When I run this code, The output is ,

```
        $./a.out
        $Enter a age  28
         Enter a college:Yale 
        $
```

Even when I tried giving different values to the age ,The output is still same.
Why does the  loop aborts and prints the next statement in the code?

And When I change the variable declaration i.e, I first read the character and then the age ..Now the code is working normally.
Why does that happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the integer input `age`, yo press enter and that should be count as a `char`, which assigns in `col`. You need to take care of that enter you've pressed using a `getchar()`. Look the code below:

```
int main(){
    int age;
    char col;
    printf("Enter a age ");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    getchar();  // the enter which you hit after taking age as an integer input
    printf("Enter a college:"); 
    scanf("%c",&col);
    if(age>=25 && (col=='H' || col=='Y'))
    printf("Harvard");
    else
    printf("Yale");

    return 0;
}
```